# How to load javascript library with require instead of import

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm creating a node.js AWS Lambda serverless app and trying to include simmerjs https://github.com/gmmorris/simmerjs.

The example in the docs use **import Simmer from 'simmerjs'** which, of course throws a syntax error in ES5.  I am using the aws SAM cli for my local dev environment. The sam invoke command starts a Docker container running Node.js v10.15.3.

This version does not support ES6 without the --experimental-mode flag.  So far, I have not found a way to start the container with the --experimental-mode enabled.

Is there any way to load the simmerjs using the ES5 require('simmerjs') syntax?  I have tried but it returns a *"TypeError: Simmer is not a constructor"* error when I try to create a new object.

Here's a code excerpt with my tried and failed results in the comments.  I can load the file but cannot create an object.

```
// top of index.js 

// all statements below cause SyntaxError: Unexpected token
//import Simmer from 'simmerjs';
//import Simmer from './simmerjs';
//import { Simmer } from './simmerjs';

// Statement works but causes "TypeError: Simmer is not a constructor" error
// later when trying to instantiate an object
const Simmer = require('simmerjs');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sql = require("mssql");
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
var steps = new Array();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    .
    .
    .
    omitted for clarity
        elements = await convertElements(elArray, prevDom);
}

const convertElements = async (fromArray, dom) => {
  // {dom} contains a jsdom window object - tried with document object as well   

  // all code below returns "TypeError: Simmer is not a constructor" error
    const mysimmer = new Simmer(dom,'{specificityThreshold: 100}',false);
  //const mysimmer = new Simmer(dom);
  //const simmer = new Simmer(dom, null, false);
  //let simmer = new Simmer(dom);
  //var simmer = new Simmer(dom,null, null);

  //Does not return "constructor error" but it gets the same results as 
  // new Simmer() can not use the object
  //const simmer = Simmer;  

  . 
  . omitted for clarity
  .
 }
```

According to the docs:

```
By the book:
    import Simmer from 'simmerjs'
    const simmer = new Simmer()
    const el =  document.getElementById('#SomeElement')

Docs Node example:
    import Simmer from 'simmerjs'
    const virtualWindow = new JSDom()
    const simmer = new Simmer(virtualWindow)
    const reconfiguredSimmer = simmer.configure({ /* some custom configuration */ })
```

I should be able to create a new simmer object from the Simmer library.  Alternatively, if I could find a way to enable experiment-mode both locally and when deployed I should be able to use the ES6 syntax.

### Update

To get this to work with commonJS, I have to specify the default constructor.

```
const Simmer = require('simmerjs').default;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You would just do

```
...
var Simmer = require('local/path/to/dist/simmerjs');
var whatever = new Simmer(virtualWindow)
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error that way.  The good news is that it is his code not mine, the bad news is that its his code not mine.  

I've reached out the the dev on github.
// this causes a "window is undefined" error message
const Simmer = require("./node_modules/simmerjs/dist/simmer.js");

Comment: Technically your answer is correct.  But I still have the issue but its an ES6 incompatibility now. The dist version is meant to be a drop-in for html and expects to find a window object.  The module is for node and it is ES6.